# Compare 2 JSON and retrieve subset from one of them based on condition in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have two JSON files `abc.json` and `xyz.json`.
Content in `abc.json` is:

```
[{"id": "121",
  "name": "John",
  "location": "europe"
 },
 {"id": "100",
  "name": "Jane",
  "location": "asia"
 },
 {"id": "202",
  "name": "Doe",
  "location": "america"
 }
]
```

Updated -> Content in `xyz.json` is:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
     "id": "111",
     "city": "sydney",
     "profession": "painter"
     },
     {
      "id": "200",
      "city": "istanbul",
      "profession": "actor"
     },
     {
      "id": "202",
     "city": "seattle",
     "profession": "doctor"
     }
    ],
   "count": {
    "type": "Total",
    "value": 3
  }
}
```

I want to get those records of `abc.json` in when the `id` in both objects are equal.In this case:

```
{"id": "202",
  "name": "Doe",
  "location": "america"
 }
```

I need to do this in Powershell and the version I am using is 5.1.This is what I have tried:

```
$OutputList = @{}

$abcHash = Get-Content 'path\to\abc.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$xyzHash = Get-Content 'path\to\xyz.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$xyzResp = $xyzHash.value

foreach($item in $xyzResp){
    foreach ($record in $abcHash){
        if ($item.id -eq $record.id){
          $OutputList.Add($record, $null)
        }
    }
}

Write-Output $OutputList
```

But on printing the OutputList , I get like this:

```
Key: @{"id": "202",
  "name": "Doe",
  "location": "america"
 }
Value:
Name:@{"id": "202",
  "name": "Doe",
  "location": "america"
 }
```

What I require is more of a PSObject like:

```
id: 202
name:Doe
location:america
```

I tried using `Get-Member` cmdlet but could not quite reach there.
Is there any suggestion I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your example xyz.json because there was an extra comma in there that should not be there. Also, the example did not have an iten with `id` 202, so there would be no match at all..

**xyz.json**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
     "id": "111",
     "city": "sydney",
     "profession": "painter"
     },
     {
      "id": "202",
      "city": "denver",
      "profession": "painter"
     },
     {
      "id": "111",
     "city": "sydney",
     "profession": "painter"
     }
    ],
   "count": {
    "type": "Total",
    "value": 3
  }
}
```

That said, you can use a simple `Where-Object{...}` to get the item(s) with matching id's like this:

```
$abc = Get-Content 'path\to\abc.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$xyz = Get-Content 'path\to\xyz.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# get the items with matching id's as object(s)
$abc | Where-Object { $xyz.value.id -contains $_.id}
```

Output:

```
id  name location
--  ---- --------
202 Doe  america
```

Of course you can capture the output first and display as list and/or save to csv, convert back to json and save that.

Comment: this worked absolutely fine for me . Thank you!! I have also updated the xyz.json file in the query.